# Javascript runnning only in debug mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function in my `script.js` file:

```
function loadMarqueeHTMLs(){
    $("#voiceInteractions").load("xmlTest1A.html");
    $("#nonvoiceInteractions").load("xmlTest1B.html");
    var voiceintelements = $("#voiceInteractions").find(".value");
    alert("Before each"); // this alert runs
    voiceintelements.each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id')); // this alert DOESN'T run
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
            case "intsWaiting":
                alert("inside intsWaiting"); // this alert DOESN'T run
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

The `alert()` before the `each` runs, but the other 2 don't run.
Unless, I run it in debug mode (Firefox) in which everything runs as expected. 
While in debug mode, I see that `voiceintelements` has the correct selection of elements and how `each` properly loops through them.

In case it helps, this is how I call the `loadMarqueeHTMLs` function from my `index.html`file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadMarqueeHTMLs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to wait voiceInteractions to load.

Comment: Create a callback function for jQuery load and then run the code inside it.

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wait voiceInteractions to load, when you run this var `voiceintelements = $("#voiceInteractions").find(".value");` the `$("#voiceInteractions")` content not loaded so `voiceintelements = $("#voiceInteractions").find(".value")` is empty

```
function loadMarqueeHTMLs(){
    alert("Before each"); // this alert runs
    $("#voiceInteractions").load("xmlTest1A.html", function(){
             $("#nonvoiceInteractions").load("xmlTest1B.html", function(){
                 var voiceintelements = $("#voiceInteractions").find(".value");
                 voiceintelements.each(function() {
                 alert($(this).attr('id')); // this alert DOESN'T run
                 switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
                     case "intsWaiting":
                           alert("inside intsWaiting"); // this alert DOESN'T run
                           break;
                      default:
                           break;
                 });
         }
      });
    });


}
```

Comment: Great!!! Now, I want to call the same function again for my next load. What's the best practices way of doing that?

Comment: code updated. please check it. you call load in call back of callback of first load.